# How can I create a dictionary by combining items from two lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
key_list=['number','alpha']
value_list=[['1','a'],['2','b']]
```

I want to collect elements in this pattern:

```
dict = {}
dict.setdefault(key_list[0],[]).append(value_list[0][0])
dict.setdefault(key_list[0],[]).append(value_list[1][0])
dict.setdefault(key_list[1],[]).append(value_list[0][1])
dict.setdefault(key_list[1],[]).append(value_list[1][1])
```

How to do this in loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) comes in very handy for this sort of thing:

```
key_list=['number','alpha']
value_list=[['1','a'],['2','b']]
d = dict(zip(key_list, zip(*value_list)))
print(d)
```

Output

```
{'alpha': ('a', 'b'), 'number': ('1', '2')}
```

Basically this works by unpacking `values_list` so that the individual items (themselves lists) are passed as arguments to the `zip()` builtin function. This has the affect of collecting the numbers and alphas together. That new list is then zipped with `key_list` to produce another list. Finally a dictionary is created by calling `dict()` on the zipped list.

Note that this code does rely on the order of elements in `value_list`. It assumes that the numeric value always precedes the alpha value. It also produces a dictionary of *tuples* not *lists*. If that is a requirement then using a dict comprehension (as per thefourtheye's answer) allows you to convert the tuples to lists as the dictionary is built:

```
key_list=['number','alpha']
value_list=[['1','a'],['2','b']]
d = {k: list(v) for k, v in zip(key_list, zip(*value_list))}
>>> print(d)
{'alpha': ['a', 'b'], 'number': ['1', '2']}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the values of the `values_list` and then `zip` the result with the `key_list`, with dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in zip(key_list, zip(*value_list))}
{'alpha': ('a', 'b'), 'number': ('1', '2')}
```

---

You can understand this, step-by-step, like this

```
>>> list(zip(*value_list))
[('1', '2'), ('a', 'b')]
```

Now, `zip`ping this with `key_list` will give us

```
>>> list(zip(key_list, zip(*value_list)))
[('number', ('1', '2')), ('alpha', ('a', 'b'))]
```

Now, you can either use `dict` function to create the dictionary, like shown by mhawke,

```
>>> dict(zip(key_list, zip(*value_list)))
{'alpha': ('a', 'b'), 'number': ('1', '2')}
```

or use the dictionary comprehension, as I have shown above.

Comment: Thank You! but l don't understand why there is a '*' before value_list

Comment: @Sbioer It [unpacks](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the values of `value_list` and passes all of them as parameters to `zip` function.

Comment: One more question. How to turn that tuple into a list?

Comment: @Sbioer You can simply use `list` function to do it. For example: `list((1, 2, 3))` will give you `[1, 2, 3]`. But unless you want to keep updating the values in the dictionary, tuples would be better than lists.